# Default UINavigationBar titleView frame incorrect after custom UINavigationBar display

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I've created a category on UIViewController called `UIViewController+CustomNavigationBar` to easily handle the display and removal of a custom-designed UINavigationBar subclass through just three lines of code!

However, one of the issues I'm encountering is that when I pop the view controller that displays my custom navigation bar, the vertical centering of the titleView of the previous view controller's stock UINavigationBar appears incorrectly.

Since this is a little hard to describe, here's a link to an animated GIF of the issue: https://github.com/kenmhaggerty/UIViewController-CustomNavigationBar/blob/demo/Sample%20Project/Issue%20Demo.gif

I'm doing a lot in my code, so I've also [posted it to GitHub](https://github.com/kenmhaggerty/UIViewController-CustomNavigationBar/tree/demo). Some key points though are:

- I set my custom UINavigationBar using `[self.navigationController setValue:navigationBar forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(navigationBar))]` within swizzled implementations of `-[viewWillAppear:]` and `-[viewWillDisappear:]` in my category.
- I am using Auto Layout to size my custom UINavigationBar.
- When my view controller using my custom navigation bar will appear, I store the existing navigation bar and re-set it back to the navigation controller when my view controller with custom navigation bar is popped.
- Because this issue is affecting my original view controller, that view controller's `navigationItem.titleView` is nil, so I can't (seemingly) adjust the title view's frame manually.

Any idea why this weird layout issue might be occurring? Also, there are other inconsistencies, so if you have the time, please do fork + check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by re-setting the navigation bar with a new instance of UINavigationBar!